# Backbone and scope of the Dom relative to a view

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a template that contains a form that needs to accept a user's full address for a stop on a route. A route can have multiple stops.

I've created a view called "StopView", which is associated with a model called "Stop".

Here is the code for the StopView and adding a new Stop:

```
StopView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el:"#stops",

    template: stopTpl,
    initialize: function() {

        this.o = StopsArray.length;
        //console.log(this.o);
    },
    render: function() {
        $(this.el).html(_.template(this.template));
        return this;

    },
    events: {
        // "keypress #test": "submit",
        "click #another": "another",
        "typeahead:selected .typeahead": "onSelected"
    },
    another: function() {
        StopsArray.add(this.model);
```

Here is the code that creates a new view and appends the template, it's part of a parent view called AppView. It happens on the collection (of stops) changing:

```
addStop: function ()
    {
        var theStop = new StopView({model:new Stop()});
        if(StopsArray.length==1)
        {
            theStop.render();
        }
        else
        {
            theStop.$el.unbind()
            theStop.$el.append(_.template(theStop.template));
            theStop.setElement('#stops');
        }
```

Now, I'm trying to apply text to all the values in a form inside that #stops tag. But when I do, it applies to BOTH sets of inputs, instead of just the current stop view's inputs.

Basically, on append I need to shift the scope of the view to the NEW html that was appended, instead of ALL of the html (including what was rendered from the first view).

I'm not sure, but I read from the todo.js example that Backbone is supposed to know which Dom element you are on, even if they are the same:
http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/docs/todos.html#section-16

Edit: And yes, I'm using "this.$('#domelement') when grabbing / changing the values of the input fields to make sure it's associated with that view.

Edit2: Basically the html looks like:

```
<div id="stops><form id="test_form">content</form></div>
```

Edit3: Here's the stops template and the index file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/typeahead_function.js"></script>   

<form id="test_form" class="form-group form-horizontal form-sqaure">
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-7" style="float:left">
        <div class="webres-stop panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading first-heading">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#first<% print(StopsArray.length) %>">
                    <h2>Stop <% print(StopsArray.length) %> <button type="button" class="btn btn-square" id="another" style="float:right">Add Stop</button></h2> 
                </a>
            </div>
            <!-- This is the actual stop content -->
            <div id="first<% print(StopsArray.length) %>" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="address" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Address: </label>
                        <div class="col-lg-7">
                            <input id="test" name="address" type="text" class="address typeahead form-control form-control-square" placeholder="Enter an address">
                        </div>  
                    </div>

                    <div id="datetime" class="form-group">
                        <label for="datetime" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Date and Time: </label>
                        <div class="col-lg-7">
                            <input class="form-control form-control-square" type="text" name="datetime">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#second<% print(StopsArray.length) %>">
                            Address Details
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="second<% print(StopsArray.length) %>" class="panel-collapse collapse" data-target>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                                    <label for="address">Street Number: </label>
                                    <input class="form-control form-control-square" type="text" id="StreetNumber" name="StreetNumber">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                                    <label for="address">Street: </label>
                                    <input class="form-control form-control-square" type="text" name="StreetName">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                                    <label for="address">City: </label>
                                    <input class="form-control form-control-square" type="text" name="City">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                                    <label for="address">State: </label>
                                    <input class="form-control form-control-square" type="text" name="State">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                                    <label for="address">Postal Code: </label>
                                    <input class="form-control form-control-square" type="text" name="Zipcode">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                                    <label for="address">County: </label>
                                    <input class="form-control form-control-square" type="text" name="Country">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#third<% print(StopsArray.length) %>">
                            Airport Information
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="third<% print(StopsArray.length) %>" class="panel-collapse collapse" data-target>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group col-lg-2">
                                    <label for="address">Airline: </label>
                                    <input class="form-control form-control-square" type="text" name="airline">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-lg-10">
                                    <label for="address">Flight Number: </label>
                                    <input class="form-control form-control-square" type="text" name="flight_number">
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                                        <label for="address">Flight Time: </label>
                                        <input class="form-control form-control-square" type="text" name="flight_time">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                                        <label for="address">Terminal: </label>
                                        <input class="form-control form-control-square" type="text" name="terminal">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
               $('#datetime').datetimepicker();
            });
```

```
<body style="background-color:#3366CC">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div id="header">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div id="content">
                </div>
                <br /><br />
                <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                    <div id="stops"></div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div id="footer">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You've hardcoded the `StopView` to have an id of `stops`:

```
StopView = Backbone.View.extend({

  el:"#stops",

  ...

});
```

Since it appears you are creating these views in memory on the fly, you will want to simply use the element type, say `div`, instead. You can also use any of the following to "tag" for later reference:

```
StopView = Backbone.View.extend({

  el:"div",
  className: "stops",
  id: "stop1"
  ...

});
```

Keep in mind that you don't need to use any of the above and Backbone will default to making the view element type "div" with no id or class names.

Comment: It doesn't have to exist at all – but like all HTML, you want to make sure your id is unique to the document. I've updated for a further explanation.

Comment: Also, you could always make the id unique by appending the model id if this view is associated with a model.

Comment: But, how will it know which elements belong to which view? Also how would it know where on the page to insert the template? I've updated my question with a basic explanation of the html. How would it know to put the template inside #stops? And what should I make the html look like if it needs to change?

Comment: Based on what you posted, I'm assuming that you want to add multiple views into that div with id stops?

Comment: yes, sorry if that was not clear, it would have been difficult to post the whole template because it's a lot of html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48094/discussion-between-jibsales-and-axschech)

Comment: div is the default type used to contain all views

Answer (score 0):

HTML IDs have to be [unique to the entire document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.id).  You can have as many elements as you like with the same class name, but each ID can only be used once.

In fact, many modern web development practices [avoid the use of IDs](http://oli.jp/2011/ids/) completely and it's not a bad idea, in my opinion.